# Create "loop" to drop tables with specific names/criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently, I am trying to drop multiple tables from my database. But only those which names begin with a specific string, or tables names match exactly my wildcard/underscore criteria.

In Oracle, I used something like that and I am looking for something equivalent to it in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
begin
  for i in (select TABLE_NAME 
              from  USER_TABLES 
              where TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_____NAME'
             )
  loop
    execute immediate 'DROP TABLE '||i.TABLE_NAME||' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE';
  end loop;             
end;
```

As I started to use SQL Server I began to realize, that SQL Server does not offer simples loops.

I managed to create something like that:

```
SELECT 'IF OBJECT_ID(''' +TABLE_NAME + ''') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE [' + TABLE_NAME + '] END;' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TABLE_____NAME'
```

...which gave me at least a list to copy-paste. I assume that solution above is a but overkill in term of checking the object id, but it works fine. I'm not sure if checking for the Object id is necessary at all.

In the end, I am seeking a simpler solution, mainly for a loop-like solution like I use to do in Oracle. I never know how many tables it will be, so a counter solution (which I find often during research) is not an option (at least as far I understand).

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Does anyone know how to realize the Oracle loop in SQL Server to work

Comment: [`WHILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) seems pretty simple?

Comment: a Cursor could also be used for this, not as simple as a while but it would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use "while" to iterate through the script texts extracted by the identity column in the prepared script table.

```
Declare @RowNumber As Int = 1
Declare @Cnt As Int
Declare @schema_name sysname = '<your schema>'
Declare @QueryText nVarChar(max)

Create Table #Script (ID Int Identity(1,1), QueryText nVarChar(max))

Insert Into #Script (QueryText)
Select Concat(N'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''',
                          Quotename(@schema_name), N'.',Quotename([name]),N''') AND type in (N''U'')) DROP TABLE ',
                          Quotename(@schema_name), N'.',Quotename([name]))
From sys.tables 
Where [name] Like 'TABLE_____NAME'

Select @Cnt = Count(*) From #Script

While (@RowNumber<=@Cnt)
    Begin
        Select @QueryText = QueryText From #Script Where ID=@RowNumber

        Exec sp_executesql @QueryText

        RAISERROR ('%s', 0, 1, @QueryText) WITH NOWAIT

        Select @RowNumber=@RowNumber+1
    End
```

or you can use string_agg to get a script to delete all tables and run it in one go without using a loop.

```
Declare @QueryText nVarChar(max)
Declare @max nVarChar(max) = ''
Declare @schema_name sysname = '<your schema>'

Select @QueryText=String_Agg(Concat(@max, N'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''',
                                           Quotename(@schema_name), N'.',Quotename([name]),N''') AND type in (N''U'')) DROP TABLE ',
                                           Quotename(@schema_name), N'.',Quotename([name])), ' ')
From sys.tables 
Where [name] Like 'TABLE_____NAME'

Execute sp_executesql @QueryText
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer :) somehow studio tells me it completed successfully, but my tables are still existend. The underscores ' _ ' are used as wildcards, does it still work that way?
Your seconds, more shorter approach looks pretty nice still :)

Comment: Hey, you are welcome. If the underscore means any single character, then you need "Like" operator. I changed the solution using Like. In any case, it is strongly recommended to examine contents of the @QueryText variable before executing it via sp_executesql.

Comment: You should also specify the actual name of the table schema instead of <your schema>.

Comment: Thanks, that was the reason, stupid that i havent seen it myself :)
Your shorter solution works well, it does the job :)
Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. I was a pleasure to help.

Answer (score 2):

Dropping tables is presumably a one-time process and something you really want to be sure about.

I normally just dynamically generate a list of `drop` statements which you can then paste directly into a Management Studio query window to visually confirm they are correct and then you can just execute the script.

```
select Concat_Ws(' ','drop table', QuoteName(name), ';')
from sys.tables
where name like 'TABLE_____NAME'
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. The idea was to do it without a pre-check.  But having all those commands to fire up afterwards would be nice.

Comment: @lilaaffe In my experience, automating dropping objects is a ticking clock to something unexpected happening, however you could simply assign the above to a string and `exec` it.